# Spring application with two different SecurityFilterChains

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with SecurityFilerChains. In my application I have two entities with users: one for Employees and the second for Visitors. For this reason, I have login pages for each of the entities. Also, I created two SecurityFilterChains, but every time I try to log in, the application opens only the webpage dedicated for employees. Also, when I put correct credentials for an employee, I receive information that the credentials are incorrect.

Here is my code for the SecurityConfig class:

```java
package com.jarema.lukasz.Meeting.Application.security;

import com.jarema.lukasz.Meeting.Application.services.impls.CustomEmployeeDetailsService;
import com.jarema.lukasz.Meeting.Application.services.impls.CustomVisitorDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class EmployeeSecurityConfig {

    private CustomEmployeeDetailsService customEmployeeDetailsService;
    private CustomVisitorDetailsService customVisitorDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeSecurityConfig(CustomEmployeeDetailsService customEmployeeDetailsService,
                                  CustomVisitorDetailsService customVisitorDetailsService) {
        this.customEmployeeDetailsService = customEmployeeDetailsService;
        this.customVisitorDetailsService = customVisitorDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain employeeSecurityFiletChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/employeeLogin").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/admins/**").hasAuthority("ADMINISTRATOR")
                .requestMatchers("/employees/**").hasAuthority("EMPLOYEE")
                .requestMatchers("/receptionists/**").hasAuthority("RECEPTIONIST")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/employeeLogin")
                .usernameParameter("emailAddress")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/employeeLogin?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(employeeSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(employeeFailureHandler());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain visitorSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers( "/visitorLogin", "/register").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/visitors/**").hasAuthority("VISITOR")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/visitorLogin")
                .usernameParameter("emailAddress")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/visitorLogin?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(visitorSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(visitorFailureHandler());

        return http.build();
    }

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(customEmployeeDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        builder.userDetailsService(customVisitorDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler employeeSuccessHandler() {
        return ((request, response, authentication) -> {
            for (GrantedAuthority auth : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
                if (auth.getAuthority().equals("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
                    response.sendRedirect("/admins/welcome");
                    return;
                } else if (auth.getAuthority().equals("EMPLOYEE")) {
                    response.sendRedirect("/employees/welcome");
                    return;
                } else if (auth.getAuthority().equals("RECEPTIONIST")) {
                    response.sendRedirect("/receptionists/welcome");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler visitorSuccessHandler() {
        return ((request, response, authentication) -> {
            for (GrantedAuthority auth : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
                if (auth.getAuthority().equals("VISITOR")) {
                    response.sendRedirect("/visitors/welcome");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private AuthenticationFailureHandler employeeFailureHandler() {
        return ((request, response, exception) -> {
            String errorMessage = "Błędny login lub hasło";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
            response.sendRedirect("/employeeLogin?error");
        });
    }

    private AuthenticationFailureHandler visitorFailureHandler() {
        return ((request, response, exception) -> {
            String errorMessage = "Błędny login lub hasło";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
            response.sendRedirect("/visitorLogin?error");
        });
    }
}
```

Here is also the link to my GitHub repository: https://github.com/LukaszJarema/Meeting-Application

Comment: Hello.
I am still can not find the problem in my code.

Can someone tell me what is needs to do to resolve it?